# Undefined Referrence

Tags: c++, oop

I am have created two classes, Room and Customer. Room has Customer as data member and Customer also has Room as data member. I have created seperate cpp files for each class. When i compile my main.cpp, it says " undefined reference to `Room::Room()' ".

Room.h file

```
class Customer;

    class Room{

    private :  
             Customer *obj1;
    public:
    Room();
    }
```

Customer.h file

```
    class Room;

    class Customer{

    private:
       Room *obj;
      };
```

Room.cpp file

```
    Room::Room(){ obj1->setName(a); // this line has the problem}
```

main.cpp file

```
#include "Room.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Room a;
}
```

Note: In customer class i have written the code for setName function along with  constructors.

Comment: You didn't actually compile Room.cpp

Comment: I think you've simplified the example too much and left out important information. You always want to provide an example that exhibits the behaviour you want solved. In this case you should give a program that compiles and has exactly one linker error. Because we don't have this, we can't tell you exactly what the problem is. This makes the question "Unclear" and "Not Useful".

Comment: @drescherjm I am using written the code on notepad in ubuntu.

Comment: @user253751 How to do that? I am compiling on terminal, if i write g++ -o exe1 main.cpp Room.cpp, there is new error Undefined ,reference to Customer:: Customer (), if i write g++ -o exe1 main.cpp Customer.cpp, there is a similar error.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Room::Room(){ obj1->setName(a); // this line has the problem}
```

you object **obj1** is null you must instantiate your object with **new**(create new object)

Comment: Even worse, it is *uninitialized*.

Comment: I think this is one of the problems. The second is `Room.cpp` is most likely not being compiled as part of the executable

Comment: If you mean create it in heap, i have done it.